The meaning of partial derivatives with respect to Gateaux derivative
I've seen the Gateaux Derivative defined as:
Let $X$ be a Banach space, $u,v \in X$, and $E: X \to \mathbb{R}$. The Gâteaux Derivative of $E$ at $ u \in X$ is defined as:
$$
  \delta E(u ; v) =   E'(u ; v) \stackrel{\text{ def }}{=}  \lim_{\lambda \to 0^{+}} \frac{E(u + \lambda v) -E(u)}{\lambda} = \frac{\partial E(u + \lambda v)}{\partial \lambda} \Big|_{\lambda=0} 
$$
I've been trying to apply the definition to a (non-differentiable) example, and run into problem with the partial derivative notation.
Let $E: C^{1}[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be the functional defined, at $u \in C^{1}[0,1]$ by:
$$
  E(u) := \int_{0}^{1} |u(x)| d{x}
$$
Then, at "point" $u(x) := 0$, and for direction $v(x) := x$, we have :
$$
  E(u+\lambda v) = \int_{0}^{1} |u(x) + \lambda v(x)| d{x} = \int_{0}^{1} |0 + \lambda x| d{x} = | \lambda | \int_{0}^{1} |x| d{x} = \frac{ | \lambda| }{2}
$$
And:
$$
  E(u+\lambda v) - E(u) = \frac{ | \lambda| }{2}
$$
i.e.:
$$
  \frac{\partial E(u+ \lambda v)}{\partial \lambda}  = \frac{1}{\lambda} \frac{| \lambda |}{2} = \begin{cases} 1/2, & \lambda > 0 \\ -1/2, & \lambda < 0 \end{cases} 
$$
The last expression doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Specifically, when trying to evaluate
$$ \frac{\partial E(u+ \lambda v)}{\partial \lambda} \Big|_{\lambda =0} 
 $$
It's not defined. Now I know the function is not Gateaux-differentiable here, and the fact it is not defined is the proof of its non-differentiability. I just feel like I've made a mistake with the notation somewhere, because this doesn't feel rigorous.

So it turns out that when looking at
$$\frac{\partial E(u+ \lambda v)}{\partial \lambda} $$ we're actually looking at the function $f(\lambda) = E(u + \lambda v)$, and then $\delta E (u ; v) = f'(0)$, if that exists. So in our case we have:
define
$$
  f (\lambda) = E(u + \lambda v) = \int_{0}^{1} | u + \lambda v |(x)  d{x} = | \lambda |
  \int_{0}^{1} | x | d{x} = | \lambda | \frac{1}{2}. 
$$
Differentiating with respect to $\lambda$, we get:
$$
  f'(\lambda) =  \begin{cases} 1/2, & \lambda >0 \\ -1/2,  & \lambda < 0 \\ \text{undefined}, & \lambda = 0  \end{cases} 
$$
Therefore we have that $\delta E (u ; v) = f'(0)$ is undefined.
